# decode html entities in angular 6

Tags: angular6

I'm looking for a library which I can decode my HTML entities in angular 6

I've tried to find something and I found a function called trustashtml in angular 2,
but I don't think so is available for 6 version.

Below you sould find my code in html template :

```
 <div [innerHTML]="post.body | markdown"></div>
```

My field post api return a native html is something like that :

```
<p style="margin: 1em 0px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.5; font-family: Lato, sans-serif;">Hey Android users! Since launching the Grammarly Keyboard for iOS, we&rsquo;ve heard from </p>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) [bypassSecurityTrustHtml()](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml) to Bypass security and trust the given value to be safe HTML, Otherwise `style` ateribute will not be rendered.

Create custom Pipe.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml' })
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Component HTML.

```
<div [innerHtml]="html | safeHtml"></div>
```

In your component define a variable that will hold the HTML value.

```
html: string = "<p style='margin: 1em 0px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.5; font-family: Lato, sans-serif;'>Hey Android users! Since launching the Grammarly Keyboard for iOS, we&rsquo;ve heard from </p>";
```

Comment: Thanks it's worked for me but  i use the pipe inside the ngOnInit function in component html didn't worked 
==> his.post.body =this.safehtmlforpost.transform(data.post.body);

Comment: Type of `post.body` should be `SafeHtml`

Answer (score 2):

You can write your code in

`[innerHTML]='post.body'`

Angular it considers as an attribute and it converts automatically in HTML.

Comment: Yes, I've solved this issue and guys bellow suggested the same as you mentioned.