# Angular 7 - Encoding and Decoding HTML Entities In [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, html-entities, html-encode, html-escape-characters, htmldecode

I am having an issue with encoding and decoding HTML Entities on a textarea using ngModel.  The Back-End needs and is sending the `><"&'` as HTML Entities.  This seems like it would be easy to do this, but for the life of me I can't think of a straight/safe way to do it.

1. I need to get the data from the Back-End and render the entities as normal text to the user.
2. On save - I need to send back to the back-end the special characters of `><"&'` as entities.
3. Bonus if there is a way to do a blanket on all special characters - not needed, but why not.

   <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" [(ngModel)]="employee.comments">

Comment: Use {{}} with pipe that removes unneeded caracters –

Answer (score 1):

You can use innerhtml to load html content

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"  [innerHtml]="employee.comments" [(ngModel)]="employee.comments">
```

you can refer this for more information.

[Similar query answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232701/decode-html-entities-in-angular-6).
Alternative way [NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decode-html-entities)